# Нужен ли уникальный iv, если ключи разные?

Tags: криптография, aes

Я использую AES/CBC. И каждый раз создаю новый ключ. Насколько я знаю iv используется чтобы одинаковые строки зашифрованные при помощи одного ключа не были одинаковыми. Я каждый раз создаю новый ключ. Следует ли мне генерировать уникальные iv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первичная цель `IV` (*Initialization Vector*) состоит в защите от атаки с выбираемым текстом [Chosen Plaintext Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack), смысл в том, чтобы одинаковый текст каждый раз генерировал разный шифротекст - для чего и вводится случайный `IV`, который мутирует блоки сцепляя их друг с другом в разных комбинациях (в зависимости от моды).

Вам нужно конечно же каждый раз генерировать уникальные `IV`, причем на первый план выходит качество ГСЧ (генератора случайный чисел).

Генерация каждый раз ключа - занятие достаточно затратное (если делать правильно), поэтому обычно ключ генерируется 1 раз - дешевле таки генерировать `IV`